# Tratamento da saída de dados vindos do banco de dados em PHP

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, cakephp

Em muitos casos temos dados no banco de dados que não estão no formato que desejamos que eles sejam mostrados.

Como modo de exemplificar digamos que tenho uma tabela chamada **users** e nessa tabela um campo chamado **role** que irá armazenar o nível de acesso de um usuário. Digamos que o valor de *role* seja **ADMIN**.

Quando pretendo fazer a saída desses dados após recupera-los do banco de dados, eu não quero que o usuário veja o valor do campo *role* (que no caso é *ADMIN*) mas quero que ele veja **DIRETOR**. Esse é um exemplo fictício para exemplificar que na verdade existem muitas situações em que no banco de dados o dado armazenado é um mas a saída dele para o usuário deve ser outra.

**Minha dúvida é: como vocês costumam tratar isso a nivel de *PHP*?**

Utilizando o framework [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) eu estou atualmente usando a callback [afterFind](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind) que pega o resultado atual obtido no banco de dados e cria uma elemento a mais na array com o índice **o** e lá trato todos os dados de saída.

Um exemplo. Suponha que obtive o seguinte array de resultados vindos do banco de dados:

```
user_id => 1,
username => 'joao',
role => 'ADMIN'
```

Após passar pela minha callback, a array ficará:

```
user_id => 1,
username => 'joao',
role => 'ADMIN'
o =>
    user_id => 1,
    username => 'joao',
    role => 'DIRETOR'
```

E na hora do output, ou seja imprimir na view, apenas uso o índice **o**. Os demais são para uso interno nos controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Imagino/sugiro que você tenha uma tabela 'roles' onde determinará as permissões de cada nível de acesso. Nesta tabela você deve ter, no mínimo, uma coluna 'role' e outra 'friendlyName'.

```
+-------+--------------+
| role  | friendlyName |
+-------+--------------+
| ADMIN | DIRETOR      |
+-------+--------------+
```

E para fazer sua consulta você usaria a cláusula:

```
SELECT user_id, username, role, (SELECT friendlyName FROM roles WHERE roles.role = users.role) as friendlyRoleName FROM users;
```

O resultado deve ser algo assim:

```
+---------+----------+-------+------------------+
| user_id | username | role  | friendlyRoleName |
+---------+----------+-------+------------------+
|       1 | joao     | ADMIN | DIRETOR          |
+---------+----------+-------+------------------+
```

Para maior estabilidade do seu código, não esqueça de definir os relacionamentos entre chaves das tabelas.

Answer (score 1):

Dá pra fazer isso tanto no PHP, como no SQL, porém eu costumo armazenar os dados da role dos usuários numa tabela de roles.

No SQL, basta criar dois alias e pegar uma formatada e outra não-formatada para o nome:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.username, IF(u.role='ADMIN','DIRETOR',u.role) AS role_with_director, u.role as role_global from users u
Inner join roles r ON(u.id_fk_role=r.id_role);
```

Também dá pra usar CASE:

```
 SELECT u.user_id, u.username,
 CASE u.role
    WHEN 'ADMIN' THEN 'DIRETOR' 
    WHEN 'SALLER' THEN 'VENDEDOR'  
    WHEN 'RESALLER' THEN 'REVENDA' 
 ELSE u.role
 END as role_formated,
   u.role as role_global from users u
   Inner join roles r ON(u.id_fk_role=r.id_role);
```

No PHP eu criaria um método dentro da classe para tratar a saída:

```
private function setNameRole($role) {

 $nameRole = '';
   switch($role) {
      case 'ADMIN':    $nameRole = 'DIRETOR'; break;
      case 'SALLER':   $nameRole = 'VENDEDOR'; break;
      case 'RESALLER': $nameRole = 'REVENDA'; break;
  } 
  return $nameRole;
}
```

Ou em array:

```
 private function setNameRole($role) {

     $roleNames = array(
                    'ADMIN'    => 'DIRETOR',
                    'SALLER'   => 'VENDEDOR',
                    'RESSALER' => 'REVENDA');

     return $roleNames[$role];
 }
```